# How to know if a rectangle in xna is moving up or down

Tags: xna, chat, monogame

I'm developing a gui for my game using monogame, and im having hard times trying to figure out how

to implement a chat system,almost everything is pretty much done except for the scroller of the

chat window, so the scoller is a rectangle with an image, if i click on it and drag it will follow

the mouse Y position, i wanted to know how can i determine if the scoller is going up or down ,

positive or negative?

here it is the code:

```
 Rectangle area3 = _chatScrollBoxScrollAreaRect;

        if (area3.Contains(mousePosition))
        {
            if (mouseState.LeftButton == ButtonState.Pressed)
            {
                if (mousePosition.Y < (area3.Y + area3.Height) - 40)
                {
                    scroll = true;
                    _chatScrollerRect.Y = mousePosition.Y;

                }
            }
```

any help is greatly appreciate!!
Kind regards,
Romulo Romero

Comment: Keep the old position of mouse.Y in a variable then check if mouse.Y is less than the variable. If it is less than the variable then the scroll is moving upwards. Else it is moving down.

Comment: Thanks deathismyfriend, i tried something similar but i just applied in a wrong way, now it Works , except i will have to rethink a little since my text basevector is in the Draw method, and it updates at every frame, so the text gets back to its position at every frame =( that sucks..im 99% done with my gui, but now im stuck, cant rethink the code =(,
but thanks tho , i really appreciate your help!!
Kind regards,
Romulo Romero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep the old position of mouse.Y in a variable then check if mouse.Y is less than the variable. If it is less than the variable then the scroll is moving upwards. Else it is moving down.